# How does the arbitrariness of $\epsilon$ imply $\text{diam }\overline{E} \leq \text{diam }E$ in Baby Rudin's Theorem 3.10?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

> **Definition.** Let $E$ be a nonempty subset of $X$, and let $S$ be the set of all real numbers of the form $d(p, q)$, with $p,q\in E$. The sup of $S$ is called the diameter of $E$.
>
> **Theorem 3.10.** If $\overline{E}$ is the closure of a set $E$ in a metric space $X$, then $$\text{diam }\overline{E} = \text{diam }E.$$

Proof: Fix $\varepsilon>0$, and choose $p, q \in \overline{E}$. By the definition of $\overline{E}$, there are points $p',q' \in E$ such that $d(p,p') < \varepsilon$ and $d(q,q') < \varepsilon$. Hence $$d(p, q) \le d(p,p') + d(p', q') + d(q', q) < 2\varepsilon + d(p', q') \le 2\varepsilon +  \text{diam }E.$$

Then, it follows that $$\text{diam }\overline{E} \le 2\varepsilon + \text{diam }E$$
Since $\epsilon$ was chosen arbitrarily, we have that
$$\text{diam }\overline{E} \leq \text{diam }E.$$

**My question: How does the arbitrariness of $\epsilon$ imply $\text{diam }\overline{E} \leq \text{diam }E?$ After all, $\epsilon$ can never be exactly equal to $0$. I tried a proof by contradiction for the same, to no avail.**

Comment: if $x\le\epsilon+y$ for all $\epsilon>0$ then $x\le y$

Comment: It's a simple consequence of the archimedean property of real numers.

Comment: Did you really try a proof by contradiction? I am suspicious. If $x\le y+\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$, what happens if you suppose that $x>y$?

Comment: @TSF That's exactly the idea I had when I was trying to develop a proof by contradiction  for this claim. Can you please explain you comment in a bit more detail?

Comment: If I were to try to explain I would literally just write J.W. Tanner's comment. He basically wrote the archimedean property in quantifiers.

Comment: @TedShifrin After assuming $x > y$, I had obtained $2 \epsilon + x > 2 \epsilon + y$ but couldn't develop this argument further.

Comment: There are many ways one of them is make $\varepsilon = 1/n $ and make $n \to \infty$.
Another way is suppose that $\text{diam} \bar{E} > \text{diam} E $ then choose $\varepsilon =  \text{diam} \bar E - \text{diam}  E$ and you got a contradiction.

Comment: @PabloHerrera Ah, that's how I should have tried to argue by contradiction. I see it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two real numbers $x$ and $y$, then
$$
x\le y \iff \forall r >0 (x\le y+r)
$$
The implication $\Rightarrow$ is obvious. To see the converse, suppose $\forall r>0 (x\le y+r)$ but it is not the case that $x\le y$. This means that $y<x$, so $x-y>0$ and we can pick $r$ with $0<r<x-y$. By assumption,
$$
x\le y+r <y+(x-y)=x
$$
This is impossible.